# How to define an object type that requires a key based on a variable?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to do something like the below. The goal is to define a type that takes a variable T and then checks that that the Type contains that variable as a key. Of note, I am using `noUncheckedIndexAccess: true`.

Is this possible in TypeScript?

```
interface one {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

interface two {
  bar: string;
  foobar: string;
}

interface three {
  foobar: string;
  foo: string;
}

interface SomeType<T> {
  ..?..
}

function fn<T>(object: SomeType<T>, key: T) {
  object[key] // is defined
  //...
}

fn<"foo">(arg); // Typeof arg must be (one | three)
fn<"bar">(arg); // Typeof arg must be (one | two)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a union of all the allowed types you want to use:

```
type Allowed = one | two | three;
```

and some way to get all the keys of the allowed types:

```
type KeysOfUnion<U> = U extends U ? keyof U : never;
// KeysOfUnion<Allowed>
```

then you could define your `fn` this way:

```
function fn<T extends KeysOfUnion<Allowed>>(key: T, object: Extract<Allowed, Record<T, any>>) {
  const thing = object[key];
  //    ^?
}
```

where the type of `object` is a subset of the allowed types where the constituents have the key.

The screenshot below shows the inferred type of `object` based on the given key:

[image: demo]

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPYhQbwLAChnIyqoBcyAzmFKAOYDceBARnFGZdSPXgL556hIsRCjAB3VMhz5kLNhSq0GMoqjntFXZX1wDw0eEmRgAFlAhZGhYuoWduK4hvvb+uMAE8ADigCCAG39UMQgAE2QAXjQMZAAfYwk44zMLZTxPH2QAaQgPcgB5GABVEGB0AB4igD5I5CLkCAAPSBBQ8jrkAH5kAGtc1BgOsgwAN2g03BgAVxAEMDKQQhBygBUG5ohW9py8wpKF8oCgkNCqqoAKPo8yFYAaNCYAKwg5sgBRZqhEMEPA4LD7gAlF6oKChVb3OAgDxnACUUisCHQlGStFqamecwA2lcALrKAgAekJBAIAD1Orw3DAQOcAESqOmwujIYnIFbeCADZCsGjIAC2UxRTBQ53QKHipnMEFheBp9LkTJZbI5Pm5vIFQrAslF4qS4lQsKAA)